# mysql help...trouble returning data

Tags: mysql

On my website, I have a method that allows a logged in user to mark articles as a favourite, when logged in the articles are highlighted as being saved as a favourite, however if the user has no favourites, I cannot get the query to return any data, what is wrong with my query?

```
SELECT `job_id`, 
    COUNT(jobs.job_id) as jobs, 
    `employers`.`employer_id`, 
    `logo_small`, `logo_large`, 
    `company_name`, `job_tags`, 
    `favourite_employers`.`employer_id` AS employer 
FROM (`employers`) 
LEFT JOIN `jobs` ON `employers`.`employer_id` = `jobs`.`employer_id` 
JOIN `favourite_employers` ON `favourite_employers`.`employer_id` = `jobs`.`employer_id` 
WHERE `favourite_employers`.`user_id` = '2' 
GROUP BY `jobs`.`employer_id` 
ORDER BY `jobs`.`job_id` DESC
```

Comment: Wait, if the user has NO favorites, and you're querying for a user's favorites, then wouldn't you expect nothing to be returned...?

Comment: @dirk, do I have to run another query to see if they have favourites first?

Comment: see the answers below. Also, the [Wikipedia page on SQL Joins is quite resourceful](https://secure.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29)

Answer (score 3):

use `LEFT JOIN` instead of `JOIN` for the `favourite_employers` table

Answer (score 2):

I know this may seem silly, but did you end the query with a `;`?

Answer (score 2):

It would be good to see the DB schema but you probably need a `LEFT JOIN` for `favourite_employers`.

Answer (score 0):

The reason could be because this join:

```
JOIN `favourite_employers` ON `favourite_employers`.`employer_id` = `jobs`.`employer_id`
```

is returning nothing because there is no favorites